# Does veracode plugin have full scan capability in offline mode

Tags: eclipse, offline, veracode

We are considering  using veracode plugin in our IDE(eclipe). But our development environment is "offline" - meaning no internet access.

Does veracode plugin function (scan and show security bugs) in 'offline' mode?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. The Veracode Eclipse plugin currently can handle displaying security flaws in an "offline mode." This is done by downloading the XML version of the security results via an internet connected computer, either via the Veracode platform or one of our APIs, and making it available in the development environment e.g. via a shared drive. The plugin has a menu option to load flaw information from XML and you would simply select the previously exported flaw information. Hope this helps.